# Receive PubNub Push Notifications when app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I am working on an Android Application that is using PubNub Service as a third party for Push Notification, as you all know PubNub uses FCM when dealing with Android.

I have put the listener for the push notifications from PubNub in the Application Class:

```
pubnub.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "PubNub status: " + status.getStatusCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
            Log.d("PubNub", "PubNub Channel Name: " + message.getChannel());
            Log.d("PubNub", "PubNub Message: getMessage " + message.getMessage().toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {

        }
    });
```

Everything is working fine when the application is foreground or background, but the Problem is when the App is killed (swiped from running tasks) I am not able to receive any push notifications from PubNub.

How can I solve this problem? should I put the PubNub listener somewhere else? or how can I receive it through the `FirebaseMessagingService` class?

Comment: Receiving GCM (FCM) messages has nothing to do with PubNub. The device OS receives them and forwards them to your app. See this link https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html and this link https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/how-google-cloud-messaging-handles-doze.html

Answer (score 1):

Putting things in the `Application` class will not solve any of your problems.

When you kill the app manually by swiping it, everything in your `Application` class will be destroyed obviously. No way that Pubnub continue to receive update.

Android can also kill your app at random moment when it's in background, your `Application` class is also destroyed and doing business logic inside it is definitely not a good idea.

Finally you have to deal with [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) which will cut your internet connexion in certain condition

With all that in mind you can consider using a [service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) if your use case need it